# Demultiplexing messages from a queue to process in parallel streams using amqp?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, reactive-programming

I am trying to figure out if I can switch from a blocking scenario to a more reactive pattern.

I have incoming update commands arriving in a queue, and I need to handle them in order, but only those regarding the same entity. In essence, I can create as many parallel streams of update events as I wish, as long as no two streams contain events regarding the same entity.

I was thinking that the consumer of the primary queue would possibly be able to leverage amqp's routing mechanisms, and temporary queues, by creating temporary queues for each entity id, and hooking a consumer to them. Once the subscriber is finished and no other events regarding the entity in question are currently in the queue, the queue could be disposed of.

Is this scenario something that is used regularly? Is there a better way to achieve this? In our current system we use a named lock based on the id to prevent concurrent updates.

Comment: what do you mean for "primary queue" ?

Comment: I receive updates to an entity, lets say Address, in a queue. This is the primary queue. The updates for all the Address entities are multiplexed in this queue.

Comment: Hello @LuisMuñiz, did you remember the solution you took ? I have kinda the same issue... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 Options:

**A single queue for each entity**
And n Consumers on one Entity-Queue.

**One queue with messages of all entities**. Where the message contains data what it is for an entity. You could than split this up into several queues (One AMQP-Queue for one type of entity) or by using a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementation.

Benefits of splitting up the Entities in qmqp-queues

- You could create an ha-setup with rabbitmq
- You could route messages
- You could maybe have more than one consumer of an entity queue if it
  is necessary someday (scalability)
- Messages could be persistent and therefore recoverable on an
  application-crash

Benefits of using an internal BlockingQueue implementation

- It is faster (no net-io obviously)
- Everything has to happen in one JVM

Anyway it does depend on what you want since both ways could have their benefits.

**UPDATE:**
I am not sure if I got you now, but let me give you some resources to try some things out.
There are special rabbitmq [extensions](https://www.rabbitmq.com/extensions.html) maybe some of them can give you an idea. Take a look at a[lternate exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html) and [exchange to exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/e2e.html) bindings.

Also for basic testing, I am not sure if it covers all rabbitmq features or at all all amqp features but [this](http://jmcle.github.io/rabbitmq-visualizer/#) can sometimes be usefull. Keep in mind the routing key in this visualization is the producer name, you can also find there some examples. Import and Export your configuration.

Comment: Hi, thanks for jumping in!

I have already outlined what you describe in the first solution, but the difficulty is that I have to create a queue not by entity type, but by entity id, so these queues are temporary, and need to be created dynamically. The challenge lies in how to leverage amqp/rabbitMQ to achieve this.

Blocking queue is out of the question, the app lives in a cluster, and the lock is a strategy to avoid inconsistencies or optimistic locking failures.

Comment: Then your question should be How to consume from a temporary queue which name you don't know when you start the consumer(?) This sounds even weird. I don't see any reason splitting up your *primary* queue up into temporary ones. The only use case for temporary queues I know is for RPC-calls.

Comment: What if you create a map (entity Id to queue). When you start processing an entity, you put it to map. After it's processed you remove it from map. For each incoming message from primary queue you need to search for it's Id in the map. If you find it then you put it to the same queue. Otherwise you put it to any queue based on your load balancing.

Comment: @EugeneTo Hi. Your solution would work in a single consumer scenario. The Mao is a Registry for the currently active temporary queues. Making it multi-node would probably involve some protocol over a topic to spawn the consumers whenever a queue has been newly created.